# HTML bundle all css links and javascript scripts in one file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a website with five php pages. All of these pages have `<link>` and `<script>` to bootstrap, sweetalert, jquery and other modules. I'm not using any PHP or Javascript framework.what i want to do is have a file like

Links_and_scripts

```
<link src='bootstrap cdn'>
<link src='jquery cdn'>
<script src='bootstrap cdn'>
<script src='jquery cdn'>
etc...
```

and then link this file in all of the five pages, without having to bundle these files on my server and serve it myself and get the performance advantage of using a CDN and save some bandwidth, so that if i choose to use another module version or change CDN provider i only have to edit one file in one place.

Comment: @Quentin yes of course thats why i want to use a CDN and not bundle these files myself and serving it myself. I just want to organize these ```links``` and ```scripts``` in one file for easy maintenance

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: If you want to bundle, you can use webpack. https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: What is `bootstrap cdn` supposed to be? Something like https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/? It can serve common libraries but not custom ones. If you don't want to configure the CDN by yourself, you can use services like CloudFlare or Bunny.net that can cache the assets and act as CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`include` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) allows you to include a chunk of PHP from a file.

```
include('filename.php')
```

Comment: `require` throws an error if the file is not found, it can be more useful than having no error if the file is not readable.